# How to point multiple laravel projects on same domain?

Tags: laravel, apache, subdomain, subdirectory

I want to create two Laravel applications like below:

app1.domain.com -> points to app1 laravel. Here I am allowing multiple subdomains like wildcard subdomains.

app1.domain.com/blog -> should point to blog laravel.

Database is the same for both applications, and session will be the same.

How can point these two like above?

I have pointed like below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp64\www\app1\public"
    ServerName      app1.domain.local
    ServerAlias     *.domain.local
    <Directory "C:\wamp64\www\app1\public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        allow from all
        order allow,deny
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ## Path to laravel sub-folder
    Alias /blog/ "C:\wamp64\www\blog\public"
    <Directory "C:\wamp64\www\blog\public">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Using above config, app1 is working fine but blog application does not work. It shows forbidden error **You don't have permission to access /blog/ on this server.**

Solution:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp64\www\app1\public"
    ServerName      app1.domain.local
    ServerAlias     *.domain.local
    ## Path to laravel sub-folder
    Alias /blog/ "C:\wamp64\www\blog\public"
    <Directory "C:\wamp64\www\blog\public">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <Directory "C:\wamp64\www\app1\public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        allow from all
        order allow,deny
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

Now working fine but with in the blog application assets path not working correctly. assets pointing from main domain instead of subfolder.
it should be like 
http://app1.domain.local/blog/assets/js/login.min.js?id=c818c905d151b67566ee

but loading from http://app1.domain.local/assets/js/login.min.js?id=c818c905d151b67566ee

Comment: why not create `/blog` as a route instead, if everything uses the same database and session?

Comment: Blog was already existing application. So we are doing single based authentication for both applications